# CakePHP 2.x work with JSON response

Tags: arrays, json, api, cakephp

I am barley new to CakePHP with JSON so please excuse my (maybe) stupid question.

Right now I am trying to handle a JSON respsonse from an external API with the help of an PHP5 Class ([Hetzner Robot API](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Robot_Webservice/en#PHP_Client)) and I am able to view the content with debug() and print_r().

The output looks like this:

Array ( 

[0] => stdClass Object ( 

  [server] => stdClass Object ( 

   [server_ip] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 

   [server_number] => XXXXX 

   [server_name] => XXXXX 

   [product] => EX6 

   [dc] => 15 

   [traffic] => 30 TB 

   [flatrate] => 

   [status] => ready 

   [throttled] => 

   [cancelled] => 

   [paid_until] => 2015-05-05 

  ) 

 )

[ 1] => stdClass Object ( 

  [server] => stdClass Object ( 

   [server_ip] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 

   [server_number] => XXXXXX 

   [server_name] => XXXXX

   [product] => EX6 

   [dc] => 15 

   [traffic] => 30 TB 

   [flatrate] => 

   [status] => ready 

   [throttled] => 

   [cancelled] => 

   [paid_until] => 2015-05-05 

  ) 

 )

So, I would like to use this information in layout but I might be to stupid to understand the JSON parts the CakePHP 2.x documentation. Would someone please give me a hint where I could find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a variable in your controller as follows;

```
$json = '{"foo": "bar"}';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$this->set('my_variable', $decoded);
```

The variable `my_variable` is now availble in your layout/view.

Comment: I managed to get an array, thank you :) As you see above, this is the structure of the array. What would I need to do to show all Server IPs for examle? In my opionion it should be something like $arrayname['XX']['IP']... in a foreach loop. But I am not finding the correct parameter to get to the information.

Comment: Use the hash class. `$list = Hash::extract ($decoded, "{n}.{s}.server_ip")` This will extract it into an array of its own, provided the path to the ip addresses is correct